# Authentication and authorization of a subrequest

Tags: authentication, digital-signature, authorization

A user sends a request to a system A. The request is signed with a digital signature, so the system A can authenticate and authorize the user. Then the system A creates a series of sub-requests to systems B, C, D, ... These sub-requests are based on the original request (in other words they are semantically related to the original request), but the body of these sub-requests is absolutely different from the original request. It's also important to note that the sub-requests are not generated and send after original request immediately. It can be done during days and weeks.

In other words, a user gives a task to the system A to send requests to systems B, C, D, ... during a long enough period of time.

The problem is that the systems B, C, D doesn't trust to the system A. They requires to be sure that the sub-requests are actually based on the original request of the user. The problem is that some evil administrator of system A can send requests to systems B, C, D and have an unauthorized access to a secured information.

It seems that it's absolutely impossible to prevent such a security violation.

The only solution is to let system A to send each sub-request to the user first. The user will sign it. And then system A will send it to other systems. But it's a very complicated solution, because the sub-requests can be generated at any time during a long period. So we will have to distract the user often.

Could you please suggest another approach?

Comment: Does the client know that requests to B, C and D will be needed? If so, have the client write out the requests, sign them and include them in the request to A so that A can use them when needed.

Comment: No, he doesn't. He makes a very simple request. And system A creates a detailed sub-requests. Only system A knows what requests to B, C, D will be needed. I think system A is like an attorney. The users gives a letter of attorney to A. Then A represents the interests of the user.

Comment: And the idea is that system A (attorney, agent) should not have more permissions than the user itself. The problem is that A can represent the interests  of different users with different permissions.

Comment: I see. Can systems B, C and D determine if a request to them is actually needed based on a request to A? So could A just pass on the original request from the client and say "hey, I need you to do this to be able to fulfill this signed order from the client"?

Comment: They can't, only system A can analyze and understand the user request.

Comment: Then I think your conclusion is correct, that the best you can do is to have the user sign the requests for B, C and D. If A can predict the need for them early, it could ask the user for signatures immediately instead of waiting until the requests are issued.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that immediate sub-requests generation and signing is a good solution.

Comment: To your Thanks comment, does the user know the body of the requests in advance? How about you make the user a CA and system A subordinate one so that A can sign the sub-requests?

Comment: No, user doesn't know the body of sub-requests. System A analyzes user's request, generates sub-requests and immediately asks the user to sign them. After that system A sends signed sub-requests to B, C, D during a long period. An important thing to note is that some sub-request parameters can't be determined and signed by user immediately. So system A sends signed subrequests and unsigned parameters. It's not good, but acceptable. Your idea with CA subordinates sounds very interesting, I need time to dive into this.

Comment: One more idea is to use blockchain, but I'm not experienced enough on this topic to understand whether it's applicable or not.